# What is the best Greek word for a thrown knife?

Tags: vocabulary, greek

In the Netflix show *The Umbrella Academy*, one character has a limited form of telekinesis: he can manipulate the movement of knives that he throws.

If I wanted to give this ability a pretentious Greek name, along the lines of pyrokinesis (manipulating fire) and cryokinesis (manipulating ice), what would be a good root to use? LSJ lists several different words for knives, but I'm unclear on the differences, or if the Greeks ever used thrown knives as a weapon.

(If there's no classically-attested word for this, is there an Ancient ancestor of a Modern word for a thrown knife? I know far less about Greek knife usage than I would need to answer this.)

Comment: Frivolous? Copidokinesis, Sphagidokinesis, Smilokinesis...  Perhaps similar to πετροβολεῖν,  σφαγιδοβολεῖν ... but stones are so much cheaper than knives...

Comment: @CosmasZachos what would σφαγιδοβολεῖν be? I assume you're not throwing abattoirs (σφαγεία) around, but that's the only connection that comes to mind as a (modern) Greek  speaker.

Comment: @terdon Σφαγιδές are apparently knives used for ritual sacrifices, though I'm not sure they'd be thrown. I associate the word more with blood-sacrifice than with combat.

Comment: Σφαγίς is the sacrificial knife, but your could opt for κοπίς. You must have noted since school how treacherous a guide modern Greek can be to classical Greek... must recall the snickers at unintentionally funny passages...

Comment: OK, φάσγανον, from the same root, of linear B attestation, might be superior. Φασγανοβόλος sounds as magnificently weird as it should... When it comes to combat, I'm not sure Greeks fought that way... You throw spears, not knives... Think of the suitors' massacre in the Odyssey.

Comment: @CosmasZachos It's entirely possible there's no ancient word for a thrown knife, but is there perhaps a modern word for it, whose ancient ancestor we could use? (A bit like how there's no ancient word for electricity, but the root _electro-_ has taken on that meaning because of how it was used centuries later.)

Comment: @CosmasZachos ah, thank you. _Σφαγίς_ makes sense. I wasn't expecting an explanation that would work in modern Greek, I was only hobbled by my ignorance of Ancient Greek :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[μάχαιρα](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dma%2Fxaira) means "knife, dirk, dagger, short sword". It seems more suitable for your purpose than φάσγανον or ξίφος, both of which mean "sword" rather than "knife". (There is ξιφίδιον, a diminutive of the latter word, which does mean "small sword or knife", but using a diminutive in a compound is a bit unwieldy.) So *machaerokinesis* might fit the bill.

(To be *really* pedantic, for the second part of the compound it might be more fitting to use a form of εὐθύνω "guide, direct" instead of κινέω "move", since the ability is that of directing a knife which you've already set in motion, rather than simply moving a knife, which most of us ordinary mortals can do. But *machaereuthynsis* is a mouthful.)

Comment: I think *machaera* is the right word, but I don't like "machaerokinesis" for other reasons. Apparently ([if Wikipedia doesn't misguide me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrokinesis)), Stephen King coined the term "pyrokinesis," but it's a pretty inept combination of "pyro-" and "telekinesis." Everyone has the power to "move a dagger," but few people have the power to do so at a distance.

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's fit a spline all the way to the sublimely ridiculous.

The disk-thrower is discobolus, δισκοβόλος, with activity noun δισκοβολία.

In my sense, the best slayer-knife word is φάσγανον, and its expert thrower    φασγανοβόλος, so "fasganobolus" indulging in notional "fasganoboly"?

There might be incidental insights at the top level of the [Ancient Greek WP project](https://incubator.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wp/grc/%CE%A0%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%B4%E1%BE%B6%CF%82).

See if [κοπίς](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopis) came close.

Comment: The majority of English words from Greek that have the φ in them transliterate the letter with "ph" and not "f," but otherwise this is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about κοπίβολος? But κοπίς is a curved knife, so possibly not very good for throwing. We might also construct ῥιψακινάκης by analogy with ῥίψασπις, one who throws away his shield in flight.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree about ρίπτω. When Nausicaa plays ball with her handmaidens in Odyssey 6 the verb is used for throwing the ball, and there are several other examples of targeted throwing in LSJ, from such writers as Herodotus and Euripides.